# Вывод по времени.

Tags: php

Как сделать этот вывод:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rinok");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){

}
```

Например: 
<br>одно запись была создана 2 февраля 2012г. в 14.00.00
<br>А другая запись была создана 3 февраля 2012г. в 14.00.00
<br>То нужно вывести сначала вторую запись, а потом первую, как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rinok ORDER by data DESC ");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 Echo "запись была создана - ".$row['data']."<br />\n";
}
```

Ну так вот.

Отсортировать от последнего к первому.